# How to write in file in append mode using fcntl.h

Tags: c++, linux

Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{

int filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_RDWR | (O_APPEND |O_CREAT) ,S_IRWXO);

    if (filedesc < 0) {
    cout<<"unable to open file";
        return -1;
    }

    if (write(filedesc, "This will be output to testfile.txt", 36) != -1) {
        cout<<"writing";
        close( filedesc );
    }

    return 0;
return 0;

}
```

If i run same above second time the o/p is "unable to open file".
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: using the `perror` function will provide you with additional information about the error cause: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/perror/

Comment: mixing C and C++ is sometimes criticized, i.e., the mixture of c-open and c++-cout. consider using either exclusively.

Comment: @RudolfMühlbauer `open` is not C, it's POSIX. Unless you have a C++ POSIX wrapper to suggest I don't see what he should do about it (unless you want him to use C++ std stuff instead of POSIX).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a permission issue

Try changing

```
S_IRWXO
```

to

```
 S_IRWXU
```

It will work fine

```
S_IRWXO
```

read, write, execute/search by others

Reference http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html